# Gantt Chart react-d3

Tags: d3.js, charts, reactjs, gantt-chart, react-d3

This question is related to [Gantt chart with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679774/gantt-chart-with-d3)

I see that a pretty close implementation is available for AngularJS at https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/ 

Is there an equivalent in React?
I've checked http://www.reactd3.org/ and https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory but there is nothing at the moment that seamlessly has the Gantt features.

What would the best way be to go about this with React.
The collapsible rows and the brush are the attractive features in the Angular Gantt.

This - http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271 is the closest I got but I just want to make sure there isn't a React implementation already before I choose to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to try google charts
[Google gantt chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#overview)

Currently it is in beta so try after keeping that fact in mind.